# How to create a back button in website which works similar to Andriod back button

Tags: javascript, php

I have three pages namely A B C. IF i move from A to B and then to C. And for the back button i am using history.back(). Now when I press back button on C it redirects me to B. But when I press back button on B it should redirect me to A but it redirects it to C. How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: Sounds to me like you went `C -> B -> C`... It should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Every time users visits any page on the website I will drop a cookie, and when users clicks on back button on the page, I would read the cookie and figure out if I want to go back to that page or go somewhere else. here is example of the jquery code I would use to store the cookie per page

```
$.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});
```

Only downside of this, if user has multiple active tabs it using your app this can get messy